# Put element inside an element, which is not the parent (JQuery UI sortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've created a test page, where inside each blocks the divs are sortable. But how is it possible, to let the user drag the div out of it's parent, and put inside an another sortable div?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zq8bqufs/

Code:

```
$( ".sortable, body" ).sortable();
```

Comment: you need to use .draggable() for it

Comment: Why does each and every `<div>` has the class sortable..? why are you applying `sortable()` to body..?

Comment: I would like to reorder all of the elements, inside the body, and inside other sortables too

Comment: Why are you trying to make a tree out of sortables? Surely there must be less messy ways of doing it. Have you looked into [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `items` option to determine which items inside the element should be sortable.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zq8bqufs/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="items">asd</div>
        <div class="items">eee</div>
        <div class="items">fff</div>
        </div>
    <div class="items">asd</div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="items">vvv</div>
        <div class="items">abbsd</div>
        <div class="items">mmm</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">dsa</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    items: '.items'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `connectWith`, more about that [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists).

I updated (and simplified) your fiddle with that functionality here: http://jsfiddle.net/vrx6r264/

Comment: I cannot put the first big block into the other one